# The fastest way to fetch multiple web pages in Java

Tags: java, performance, url, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a fast HTML scraper and at this point I'm just focusing on maximizing my throughput without parsing. I have cached the IP addresses of the URLs:

```
public class Data {
    private static final ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final ArrayList<URL> URL_LIST = new ArrayList<URL>();
    public static final ArrayList<InetAddress> ADDRESSES = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

    static{
        /*
        add all the URLs to the sites array list
        */

        // Resolve the DNS prior to testing the throughput 
        for(int i = 0; i < sites.size(); i++){

            try {
                URL tmp = new URL(sites.get(i));
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(tmp.getHost());
                ADDRESSES.add(address);
                URL_LIST.add(new URL("http", address.getHostAddress(), tmp.getPort(), tmp.getFile()));
                System.out.println(tmp.getHost() + ": " + address.getHostAddress());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My next step was to test the speed with 100 URLs by fetching them from the internet, reading the first 64KB and moving on to the next URL. I create a thread pool of `FetchTaskConsumer`'s and I've tried running multiple threads (16 to 64 on a i7 Quad Core machine), here is how each consumer looks:

```
public class FetchTaskConsumer implements Runnable{
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final int[] urlIndexes;
    public FetchTaskConsumer (int[] urlIndexes, CountDownLatch latch){
        this.urlIndexes = urlIndexes;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        URLConnection resource;
        InputStream is = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < urlIndexes.length; i++)
        {
            int numBytes = 0;
            try {                   
                resource = Data.URL_LIST.get(urlIndexes[i]).openConnection();

                resource.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

                is = resource.getInputStream();

                while(is.read()!=-1 && numBytes < 65536 )
                {
                    numBytes++;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Fetch Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {

                System.out.println(numBytes + " bytes for url index " + urlIndexes[i] + "; remaining: " + remaining.decrementAndGet());
                if(is!=null){
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {/*eat it*/}
                }
            }
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

At best I'm able to go through the 100 URLs in about 30 seconds, but the literature suggests that I should be able to go through <strike>300</strike>150 URLs per second. Note that I have access to Gigabit Ethernet, although I'm currently running the test at home on my 20 Mbit connection... in either case, the connection is never really being fully utilized.

I've tried directly using `Socket` connections, but I must be doing something wrong, because that's even slower! Any suggestions on how I can improve the throughput?

P.S.
I have a list of about 1 million popular URLs, so I can add more URLs if 100 is not enough to benchmark.

**Update:**
The [literature I'm referring](http://www.cse.lehigh.edu/~brian/course/2003/searchengines/notes/High-Performance-Web-Crawling-V2.pdf) is the papers relating to the Najork Web Crawler, Najork states:

> Processed 891 million URLs in 17 Days
>   That is ~ 606 downloads per second [on] 4
>   Compaq DS20E Alpha Servers [with] 4 GB main
>   memory[,] 650 GB disk space [and] 100 MBit/sec.
>   Ethernet ISP rate-limits bandwidth to
>   160Mbits/sec

So it's actually 150 pages per second, not 300. My computer is Core i7 with 4 GB RAM and I'm nowhere near close to that. I didn't see anything stating what they used in particular.

**Update:**
OK, tally up... the final results are in! It turns out that 100 URLs is a bit too low for a benchmark. I bumped it up to 1024 URLs, 64 threads, I set a timeout of 2 seconds for each fetch and I was able to get up to 21 pages per second (in reality my connection is about 10.5 Mbps, so 21 pages per second * 64KB per page is about 10.5 Mbps). Here is what the fetcher looks like:

```
public class FetchTask implements Runnable{
    private final int timeoutMS = 2000;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final int[] urlIndexes;
    public FetchTask(int[] urlIndexes, CountDownLatch latch){
        this.urlIndexes = urlIndexes;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        URLConnection resource;
        InputStream is = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < urlIndexes.length; i++)
        {
            int numBytes = 0;
            try {                   
                resource = Data.URL_LIST.get(urlIndexes[i]).openConnection();

                resource.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMS);

                resource.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

                is = resource.getInputStream();

                while(is.read()!=-1 && numBytes < 65536 )
                {
                    numBytes++;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Fetch Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {

                System.out.println(numBytes + "," + urlIndexes[i] + "," + remaining.decrementAndGet());
                if(is!=null){
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {/*eat it*/}
                }
            }
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: setting a browser useragent for a scraper is **not** good practice.

Comment: Literature? You mean to say javadocs? I can't find anything about 300 URLs per second related to URLConnection.

Comment: URLConnection mostly gets a page per 500ms, java is quite slow in that purpose

Comment: @Mat, sometimes I have to impersonate a browser because web sites may change their content depending if the page is being served to a browser or a bot and if I'm scraping for content, then I don't want to miss content that would be valuable to users. I still comply with the robots.text tho.

Comment: @Lirik: the sites that do that do it on purpose. You could very well be violating their usage policies.

Comment: @Mat: how is the scraped data of any value if it doesn't represent what the user would see? Spammers hide all sorts of content that's only visible to users, I'd love to catch them.

Comment: @Lirik: if a site decides to hide data from robots, it's because they don't want robots to harvest that data. That's all there is to it. Data on webpages are of value to content producers. They use various techniques to offset the cost of hosting for instance adds. Your scraper doesn't give any value to the producers, so why should they care to give you their data?

Comment: @Mat: How would we find spam then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure of your sums?

300 URLs per second, each URL reading 64 kilo bytes

That requires: 300 x 64 = 19,200 kilo bytes / second

Converting to bits: 19,200 kilo bytes / second = ( 8 * 19,200 ) kilo bits / second

So we have: 8*19,200 = 153,600 kilo bits / second

Then to Mb/s: 153,600 / 1024 = 150 mega bits / second

... and yet you only have a 20 Mb/s channel.

However, I imagine many of the URLs you are fetching are under 64Kb in size, hence the through put appears faster than your channel. You are not slow, you are fast!

Comment: even at 20 MB/s (my home connection) I should at least be able to max it out with 40 pages per second... I'm nowhere near close to that (100 URLs in 30 seconds, that's about 3 pages per second)! I also have access to a 100 Mbps connection, but I'll be glad if I can max my home connection before going to 100 Mbps.

Comment: My apologies - I focused more on your expectations than your achievements. I will see what I can figure out.

Comment: it's a good point none the less... even if it doesn't really answer my question :). Now I'm looking at Nutch and how they manage to fetch so many URLs without running into the same problem as me. Perhaps they're not using `URLConnection`...

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on your achievements this time. I tried using your code myself and found I also got about 3 pages per second accessing major sites. If I accessed my own webserver downloading static pages however, I maxed my system.

On the internet today, a major site typically takes more than a second to generate a page. Having looked at the packets they are sending me just now, the page is arriving in multiple TCP/IP packets. From here in the UK, it takes 3 seconds to download www.yahoo.co.jp, 2 seconds to download amazon.com, but facebook.com takes less than 0.1 seconds. The difference is that the facebook.com front page is static whereas the other two are dynamic. For humans the critical factor is the time to first byte, which is when the browser can start doing something, not the time to the 65536th byte. No one optimises that :-)

So what does this mean for you? As you are focussing on popular pages, I imagine you are also focussing on dynamic pages, which are simply not sent as fast as static pages. As the sites I looked at are sending multiple packets for their pages, that means if you are fetching many pages simultaneously, and therefore the packets can bump into each other on the ethernet.

Packet collision happens when two websites send you a data packet simultaneously. At some point the input from the two websites has to be co-ordinated into the single wire to your computer. When two packets arrive on top of each other, the router combining them rejects both, and instructs the two senders to resend after different short delay. Effectively this slows down both sites.

So:

1) The pages aren't generated that fast these days.
2) The ethernet has trouble coping with multiple simultaneous downloads.
3) Static websites (which used to be a lot more common) are much faster and use less packets than dynamic websites.

This all means that maxing your connection is really hard.

You might try the same test I did of putting up 1000 64Kb files and seeing how fast your code can download them. For me, your code worked just fine.

Comment: Simon, I increased the batch size to 300 URLs and I got them in 60 seconds... so I'm getting better: 5 URLs per second. The literature I'm referencing is also reading the first 64KB. Nutch seems to be doing really good too: 40 pages per second. Now I set my iniatial batch of URLs to 1000 to see if there is a performance increase yet again.

Comment: I added 1024 URLs now and with the same code it's up to 21 pages per second now (fetches the 1024 in ~47 seconds).